# Doesn't underline when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Basically, I'm trying to create a Todolist app by express.js and node.js that every time that a user checks a particular checkbox of a task, it'll be underlined this particular piece of data inside the array.
However, it doesn't work and I try to do it via post HTTP.
Maybe someone could explain me what I'm doing wrong and how should I fix it?

Snippet below:

index.js

```
let taskList = [];
let viewTaskList = ["Task 1","Task 2","Task 3","Task 4"];

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));



app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        views: viewTaskList
    });  

});


app.post("/today", (req, res) => {
    
    let itemName = req.body.task;
    let button = req.body.add;
    button = true;
    if (button) {
        taskList.push(itemName);   
    }

    res.render("index.ejs", {
        task: taskList,
        views: viewTaskList
    }); 

    let checkbox = req.body.checked;
    checkbox = true;
    if (checkbox) {
        res.render("index.ejs", {
            underlined: checkbox
        });
    } else {
        checkbox = false;
    }


});
```

index.ejs

```
<% if (locals.task) { %>
    <% task.forEach(tasks => { %>
        <div class="checkbox-div">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checked">
            <label for="checked">
                <% if (locals.underlined) { %>
                <u> <%= tasks %></u>
                <% } else { %>
                 <%=tasks %>
                 <% } %>
            </label>
        </div>  

    <% }) %>
   <% } %>
 

<form action="/submit" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="task" placeholder="New Item">
    <button type="submit" value="Add">+</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You're calling `res.render()` twice. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: What's the point of `else { checkbox = false; }`? It's already false if you get into the `else` block.

Comment: Seems like this would be easier in CSS: `input:checked ~ label { text-decoration: underline; }`.

Comment: But `checkbox` is always true because you do `checkbox = true;` before the `if` statement. Why?

Comment: Do you want to persist the checked status on the server or is this just a temporary front end thing? If the former, keep state on the server. If the latter, don't post anything to the backend to change the CSS.

Comment: @HereticMonkey But then they need to use a conditional to add the `checked` attribute to the checkbox.

Comment: @Barmar It's using the `:checked` pseudo-class, which is automatically toggled by the browser.

Comment: @HereticMonkey But they're rendering new HTML after something has been submitted, not doing this dynamically in the existing DOM.

Comment: @Barmar That's kinda the point. There's no need to do it on the server-side when you can do it all on the client-side with CSS. It's an option, and hence why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I understood your comments. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a bit of confusion here. If your goal is to simply change the style of the checkbox and nothing more, then you can do it entirely on the front end with CSS as pointed out in the comments. No need to post data to the server or update any resources.

However, it looks like you're trying to persist the checked state on the server, as in ticking off completed todos. If this is the case, you'll want to store the checked state for each todo on the server, then use JS's fetch API on the client to PUT updates to the current task to the server.

Here's an example of what this might look like.

Server:

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // 1.20.2
const express = require("express"); // 4.18.2

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs"); // 3.1.9
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

let id = 0;
const tasks = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs", {tasks});
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  tasks.push({
    id: ++id,
    name: req.body.task,
    completed: false,
  });
  res.render("index.ejs", {tasks}); 
});

app.put("/task", (req, res) => {
  const {completed, name, id} = req.body;
  const task = tasks.find(e => e.id === +id);

  if (task) {
    task.completed = completed !== undefined;
    task.name = name ?? task.name;
  }

  res.json(task);
});

app.listen(
  5000,
  () => console.log("listening on port 5000")
);
```

Client:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .completed {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<% tasks.forEach(task => { %>
  <div class="task" data-task-id="<%= task.id %>">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" <%= task.completed ? "checked" : "" %>>
      <span
        class="task-name <%= task.completed ? "completed" : "" %>"
      >
        <%= task.name %>
      </span>
    </label>
  </div>  
<% }) %>
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input name="task" placeholder="New Item">
  <button type="submit" value="Add">+</button>
</form>
<script>
document
  .querySelectorAll('.task [type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", e => {
      const div = e.target.closest(".task")
      div.querySelector(".task-name").classList.toggle("completed");
      const formData = new FormData();
      const id = +div.dataset.taskId;
      formData.append("id", id);

      if (e.target.checked) {
        formData.append("completed", "");
      }

      fetch("/task", {
        method: "PUT",
        body: new URLSearchParams(formData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I haven't done any error handling in cases when fetch requests might fail or todo items may not be found, so that's left as an exercise for the reader.